# Sorting and editing a text file to output a new file

Tags: awk, scripting

There are few stages to this problem.

I have the following data and I want to sort it first on column 2 the 5 then 1. 
Then I would like to combine columns 5 and 6 together with a deliminator. 
When there is a change is values between the new 5 and 6 for it to print the new data. With at the top the new value from 5-6.

Maybe an example would help.

Original data.

```
fldr   cable   pdu_edit stu     grnd_sta chan_pdu

64      3       1       13      145     156     
66      3       1       13      145     156     
79      1       1       9       97      108     
117     3       1       13      145     156     
240     3       1       13      145     156     
255     3       1       13      145     156     
263     3       1       13      145     156     
291     3       1       13      145     156     
817     1       1       9       97      108     
946     1       1       9       97      108
```

What I would like to look like when it is printed:

```
Cable 1

97-108                         
79,817,946

Cable 3

145-156  
64,66,117,240,255,263,291
```

I haven't been able to get very far. To sort it, I was using:

```
sort -k2 -k5 -k1 filename.txt
```

Then to print it I was using:

```
awk '{if ($2==1 && $5==97) {print $1}}' filename.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g' | sort
```

But in the above case I am selecting the cable number and the number I am looking for in grnd_sta. However I am very new to this and I think I trying to run before I can walk. Not sure how to combine it together to produce an text file like the example. I was thinking I would have to use an if function so if there is a change in grnd_sta, in relation to the cable number.

Comment: Welcome! Could you describe what you have tried so far to make this work?

Comment: I haven't been able to get very far. To sort it, I was using: 
sort -k2 -k5 -k1 filename.txt

Then to print it I was using:
awk '{if ($2==1 && $5==97) {print $1}}' filename.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g' | sort

But in the above case I am selecting the cable number and the number I am looking for in grnd_sta.

However I am very new to this and I think I trying to run before I can walk. Not sure how to combine it together to produce an text file like the example. I was thinking I would have to use an if function so if there is a change in grnd_sta, in relation to the cable number.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that information

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an easy task for SQL.

`csv` + `sql` == `csvsql` from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)!

You can install it via pip.

Before you can start, you might need to fix your file before executing this: Remove the empty line and the spaces at the end of each line:

```
sed -i.bak '2d;s/[[:blank:]]*$//' file
```

---

You can go half way with:

```
csvsql \
    -d' ' -S \
    --query 'select cable,grnd_sta || "-" || chan_pdu,group_concat(fldr) from file group by cable' \
    file \
| csvformat -D' '
```

- You might need `-t` instead of `-d' '` if your file is tab delimited.
- Use  `csvformat -D' '` to get space-delimited output, as `csvsql` only outputs comma-delimited. It's easier to handle for `awk`, but csvsql will put quotes around the last column, and we don't want this!

Output:

```
cable "grnd_sta || ""-"" || chan_pdu" group_concat(fldr)
1 97-108 79,817,946
3 145-156 64,66,117,240,255,263,291
```

From here you can go on using `awk`:

```
... \
| awk 'NR>1{printf "Cable %s\n\n%s\n%s\n\n",$1,$2,$3}' \
| head -n-1
```

Output:

```
Cable 1

97-108
79,817,946

Cable 3

145-156
64,66,117,240,255,263,291
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to install pip or anything else on the system I am using. 

However thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an Awk script containing all the necessary calculations:

```
NR==1 { next }
NF==0 { next }
      { a[$2][1]= $5 "-" $6;    
        a[$2][2]= a[$2][2] $1 "," ; }
END   { for (c in a) printf "Channel %d\n%s\n%s\n\n",c,a[c][1],a[c][2] }
```

usage:

```
$awk -f x.awk data
Channel 1
97-108
79,817,946,

Channel 3
145-156
64,66,117,240,255,263,291,
```